# If a virtual method is declared abstract

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

My friend asks me if an *abstract* method could have *virtual* modifier. And I said, **No**.
Because, ***an abstract method is implicitly also a virtual method, it cannot have the modifier virtual.***

But while reading [one of the MSDN articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173150.aspx), I have seen this:

> ...
>   If a **virtual** method is declared **abstract**, it is still virtual to any
>   class inheriting from the abstract class. A class inheriting an
>   abstract method cannot access the original implementation of the
>   method—in the previous example, DoWork on class F cannot call DoWork
>   on class D. In this way, an abstract class can force derived classes
>   to provide new method implementations for virtual methods....

I can't understand first sentence correctly. Could you please, explain me what they wants to say?

Thanks.

Comment: The first sentence just means that the `abstract` keyword doesn't change anything in terms of "virtuality", i.e. the method remains `virtual`, i.e. it will still behave polymorphically.

Comment: @BartoszKP After reading Heinzi's answer and your comment, I got it. Thanks.

Comment: This might interest you: http://ericlippert.com/2011/02/07/strange-but-legal/

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks for the link. It is really very sensible. And interesting also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It becomes clearer when you look at the code example directly above the quoted paragraph:

```
public class D
{
    public virtual void DoWork(int i)
    {
        // Original implementation.
    }
}

public abstract class E : D
{
    public abstract override void DoWork(int i);
}
```

The virtual method `D.DoWork` is inherited by `E`, and, there, declared abstract. The method is *still virtual*, it has just become *abstract as well*.

As you correctly state, an abstract method is always virtual. If your friend is still unconvinced, here's an [official quote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/sf985hc5.aspx) for that:

> An abstract method is implicitly a virtual method.

Comment: **The method is still virtual, it has just become abstract as well.** This sentence was enough for me to understand.Thanks very much.

Comment: The C# keyword `abstract` (as applied to methods) is named `MustOverride` in VB.NET. I've always thought this a clumsy name, but it actually fits perfectly in the very specific scenario shown here (where a `virtual` method is made `abstract` again in a derived class).

Comment: @stakx: Indeed. `virtual` is named `Overridable`, and it makes perfect sense that `MustOverride` implies `Overridable`.

Answer (score 1):

Abstract classes may override `virtual` members with `abstract` ones:

```
public class B
{
    public virtual void M() { }
}
public abstract class D : B
{
    public abstract override void M();
}
public abstract class D2 : D
{
    public override void M() { }
}
```

The sentence says that `D2` **must** override `void M()`, because it is declared abstract in `D`. If it were declared as `D2 : B`, this would be optional, but as it stands, `D2` has to comply with the contracts specified in `D`, but `M()` will also behave like any other member overriding a "normal" virtual member, since `M()` is both virtual and abstract.